# Confirm Review Approval

Tags: script, review

### Screenshot

[image: Screenshot of Confirm Review Approval user script]

### About

This is a simple user script that brings up an extra confirmation dialog when you click "Approve" in the Suggested Edit review queue.  It was written in response to [this request](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/12810) for such a feature.

#### License

This script is released into the public domain per the [Creative Commons CC0 public domain dedication](//creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/).  Feel free to do whatever you want with it.

#### Download / Install

This user script is [hosted on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/vyznev/3033cabb38a994368bf6).  If you have a suitable user script management extension (such as [GreaseMonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) for Firefox or [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo) for Chrome) installed, clicking the ["download / install"](https://gist.github.com/vyznev/3033cabb38a994368bf6/raw/dce2388e99d164eac669c2a203cc576574b18ae8/confirm_review_approval.user.js) button below should bring up a dialog asking you if you want to install this user script:

> ## [<kbd>Download / Install</kbd>](https://gist.github.com/vyznev/3033cabb38a994368bf6/raw/dce2388e99d164eac669c2a203cc576574b18ae8/confirm_review_approval.user.js)
>
> <sup>[view source](https://gist.github.com/vyznev/3033cabb38a994368bf6)</sup>

For more information on how to install user scripts, see the [script tag wiki](https://stackapps.com/tags/script/info).

#### Compatibility

This user script has been tested on Mozilla Firefox 27 with GreaseMonkey.  It should work on any browser with a compatible user script API, including Google Chrome, Opera and Safari.

#### Known issues

The script tries to inject the confirmation dialog handler every time a new review task is loaded, but for some (currently unknown) reason, this doesn't always work.  As a safety measure, it also checks twice a second to see if a new task has been loaded, and, if so, adds the handler.

Should both of these methods fail for some reason, the "Approve" button will be shown with **red text and border** to warn you that clicking it will approve the edit without confirmation.  Moving the mouse over the button should trigger a second safety measure that will inject the handler and remove the warning color.